# AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate ERROR?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

Hello so I was trying to use the AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate.

```
extension FSVideoCameraView: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
    print("started recording to: \(fileURL)")
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: Error!) {
    print("finished recording to: \(outputFileURL)")
    self.delegate?.videoFinished(withFileURL: outputFileURL as NSURL)
}


}
```

It keeps giving me an error at:

```
extension FSVideoCameraView: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate{
```

Comment: Add your script instead of  image

Comment: I am pretty sure your method heads are off: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutputrecordingdelegate/1390612-capture

Comment: And please do what @jobairahmed said: add both the error message and the error message as actual text, not as screenshot

Comment: @luk2302 Sorry i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, I changed [AnyObject] to [Any] and it was fixed.